# Efficient method to find consecutive products in table

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

Suppose I have a table of matrices, $[A,B,C,D,...,Z]$ and a vector $v$. I would like to efficiently compute both $ABCD...Zv$ and the table $[A,AB,ABC,ABCD,...,ABCD....Z]$.

I know that to compute the product of the entire table I can do something like

```
Dot@@table
```

But how can I efficiently find the products of different length? I would like to avoid loops and explicitly limiting lengths in a table if possible, for speed.

The matrices themselves will be quite large, $\sim400 \times 400$, always square, and have complex values inside them.

Comment: Looks like something `FoldList[]` was built for: `FoldList[Dot, {A, B, C}]`. Just multiply the last in the series with your vector afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! And what about if I wanted to compute the table $[Av,ABv,ABCv,...]$?

Comment: You could just `Map[]` `#.v &` into your list of matrices. However, if the question is how to generate that list of vectors without keeping those intermediate matrices around, that is a little more interesting.